# How to get batch ID in Kafka output from Spark Structured Streaming

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming

I'm running my Spark Structured Streaming job in update mode, and can't figure out if it's possible to get the batch ID for each update. For example, when you output to the console in update mode, Spark will show each batch number as it's outputted:

```
-------------------------------------------
Batch: 0
-------------------------------------------
...
-------------------------------------------
Batch: 1
-------------------------------------------
...
```

and so forth. 
I need to add this same information to each message I send to Kafka. I'm restricted to only Spark 2.3 for this, so I can't utilize forEachBatch.

My job outputs aggregated metrics for a specific set of dimensions. Each trigger, the metrics have possibly been updated since the last trigger - the dimensions with updated metrics will be outputted in the next batch, since I'm running in update mode. When I output these to Kafka, I need to know which batch is the latest - hence needing the batch number. I think forEachBatch could get me what I need, but I unfortunately don't have access to Spark 2.4. Could I possibly use forEach to accomplish this? I'm restricted to using update mode, as it's possible late events will come in and update metrics that were already outputted previously.

Here is the console mode I'm using to test. This output shows each batch separately, and which number it is:

```
StreamingQuery query = logs.writeStream()
        .format("console")
        .outputMode(OutputMode.Update())
        .start();
```

I would like to do something like this

```
StreamingQuery query = agg.WriteStream()
    .format("kafka")
    .outputMode(OutputMode.Update())
    .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "myconnection")
    .Option("topic", "mytopic")
    .Start();
```

but still retain the ability to tell which batch a message came from in *mytopic*. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can make use of version number `long version` from `ForeachWriter`

you can implement your own KafkaCustomSink like this.

```
class KafkaCustomSink(val config: Config) extends ForeachWriter[String] {
  var producer: KafkaProducer[String, String] = _
  var _version: Long = _

  override def open(partitionId: Long, version: Long): Boolean = {
    _version = version
    val props = new Properties()
    props.put("bootstrap.servers", config(Constant.OUTPUT_BOOTSTRAP_SERVER))
    props.put("key.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer")
    props.put("value.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer")
    props.put("acks", "0")
    producer = new KafkaProducer[String, String](props)
    true
  }

  override def process(value: String): Unit = {
    //use version here
    val record = new ProducerRecord[String, String](config(Constant.OUTPUT_TOPIC), null, "version : %s, data : %s".format(_version, value))
    producer.send(record)
  }

  override def close(errorOrNull: Throwable): Unit = {
    producer.close()
  }
}
```

and assign it to

```
      logs
          .writeStream
          .outputMode("update")
          .foreach(new KafkaCustomSink(config))
          .trigger(Trigger.ProcessingTime(config(Constant.TRIGGER_INTERVAL).toInt, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
          .option("checkpointLocation", config(Constant.CHECKPOINT_LOCATION))
```